# Safari input=file file select modal clicks bubble through and land on original window.document

Tags: file, events, input, safari, event-bubbling

Have noticed this weird bug. Safari's file select modal window triggers "click" on the original window "document" when I try to select a file or click anywhere in the modal.
This breaks my functionality, cause I have an uploader put at a small popup that is supposed to close on document.click, and as you can imagine - this popup gets closed in Safari when I try to select a file for upload.

Comment: I've submitted this bug to Apple using Safari's Help->Report Bugs to Apple... dialog.

Comment: Do you have a link to the bug report as i've seen the same bug and would like to find more info regarding this.

Comment: I Got ITTTTTTTTTTTTTT Yessssssssssss 
the change event will work with safari if you just attach it in javascript 

see this link it consider how to attach the events 

http://help.dottoro.com/ljoiurdq.php